# What's overriding my local_settings.php?

Tags: configuration

I'm using a [local_settings.php file](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/stage-specific-drupal-settings-localsettingsphp), that includes several [$conf](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/conf/7) settings. All of the settings were working as expected until just recently when the mail_system setting started getting overridden somehow.

Now, if I run `$ grep mail_system local_settings.php -A2`, I get:

```
$conf['mail_system'] = array(
  'default-system' => 'DevelMailLog',
);
```

...yet, the output of `$ drush vget mail_system` is:

```
mail_system: Array
(
    [default-system] => DefaultMailSystem
)
```

I've always assumed that whatever was defined in the settings.php (or in this case the local_settings.php) would trump the same variable defined elsewhere. I've checked all the other variables I'm setting inside the $conf variable in the local_settings.php and they're set as they are in the file.

Where else might mail_system be getting set that would override the $conf definition?

Comment: Are you sure local_settings.php is still being used? Is is included from another file that then define a new value for that Drupal variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the Devel module fixed the issue. Ultimately, I think the issue is specific to the Mail System module and [the unusual way it handles settings and defaults](http://drupalcode.org/project/mailsystem.git/blob/1ba3ab876b79fe03945843c9b57a8d22f0a17b47:/mailsystem.module#l204).